# Can a Foreigner cash a US issued Check in the US?

Tags: united-states, check, cash

I have received an American check from a large US bank as payment for stocks that I sold in the US.
I am not american, and I will be in the US shortly.
I need to know if and how I could cash this check in the US without having any valid American photo ID. I have my national valid documents - drivers license, passport etc - but they are not American documents as I am not American.
Check value is of approximately five thousand USD (US$5,000.00).
Thank you!

Comment: If you can visit a branch of the large US bank that issued the check, you are more likely to be able to cash the check and receive US$ in return. If you walk into some other bank or any service that will cash a check for you, the chances of getting the check cashed are much smaller.

Comment: Most places take a passport as valid photo id.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. My passport is not American, this is the point that concerns me. Will the bank or a cash store for instance cash a check for a person from Chile or Spain - a tourist.

Comment: I had no problem (aside from a few fees and long clearing times) depositing checks from the US, both personal and bank issued checks, into my Dutch bank account in the Netherlands.  Do you need to cash it in the US or have you looked into doing it in your home country?

Comment: Thanks Eric. I need to cash it in the US. Have you done so? Cheers,

Comment: I'm on a visitor visa holiday how I got a pert time job with my next door neighbor to look their daughter and they issue me a check for $2000 wanna know if I will be able to change my check without an ussue

Comment: @Ashanti if the answers here don't answer your question, post a new question and explain why your situation is different. Asking your question as a comment on a related question isn't going to get you an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Different banks will have different policies, but in general passports are accepted as ID.

If you will be able to visit a branch of the bank where the check is drawn (not necessarily the institution who wrote you the check), it will be easier. I would call ahead to find out what their exact requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

A passport of just about any nationality will serve as identification at a US bank. Lots of people without US passports or US IDs have US bank accounts or do business in the US.

The rules sort of vary by bank (as the other answer noted), but since you're only cashing a check (not opening an account) at the issuing bank, all you need is some sort of photo ID. Some crappy banks might charge you a small fee for not having an account with them, but usually if you're a foreigner they'll waive it because you're not a resident. (If they don't waive it ask nicely for them too!)

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/101006/how-can-a-foreigner-cash-an-american-cheque-in-the-us?rq=1

This post however suggests, while it is possible, can be troublesome